# Combobox: search does not reset on blank value

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs5

I have a combobox:

```
var cmbMarket = new Ext.form.ComboBox 
({
    id: 'cmbMarket',
    fieldLabel: 'Market',
    allowBlank: false,
    store: config.marketStore,
    queryMode: 'local',
    displayField: 'marketName',
    forceSelection: true,
    valueField: 'id'
});
```

When user starts typing something in the combobox it correctly filters its contents so to help user to find what they are searching for.

Problem is that, when user leaves the combobox text blank, search does not reset!

In other words, assuming this list:

```
can
cat
coockies
...
salt
say
```

If user starts typing "c" and then leaves the combo blank, its contents are only words starting with "c", so:

```
can
cat
coockies
```

At start I though it was because of the "local" queryMode, making combo losing its data. Anyway if User writes "s" after that the list

```
salt
say
```

correctly appears, so data is still there!

Where is the problem?

Comment: Can you demonstrate this in a fiddle as it's not immediately clear what you mean?

Comment: try adding - triggerAction: 'all' - to your combo config

Answer (score 1):

What ExtJS version do you use?

I've made fiddle for you problem in Ext5.1 and Ext4.2 and it works correct. 
Look https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/j6s

```
Ext.define('App.model.Business', {
requires: [ 'Ext.data.reader.Xml' ],
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [{
    name: 'Id',
    type: 'string'
}, {
    name: 'MarketName',
    type: 'string'
}] 
});

Ext.application({
name : 'Fiddle',

launch : function() {
    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'App.model.Business',
        data : [
     {MarketName: 'coo',    Id: '1'},
     {MarketName: 'caa', Id: '2'},
     {MarketName: 'saul', Id: '3'},
     {MarketName: 'sdsq', Id: '4'}
 ]
    });

    Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        title : 'XML Model Example',
        layout : 'hbox',
        items : [{
            xtype: 'combo',
            fieldLabel: 'Market',
            allowBlank: false,
            store: store,
            queryMode: 'local',
            displayField: 'MarketName',
            forceSelection: true,
            valueField: 'Id'
        }],
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
    }
});
```

Comment: It doesn't, try the following: 1)Write "co" and select "coo". 2)backspace until the end. From now just words starting with "co" will appear and you lost others

Comment: Looks like it a bug. Report it, please. The problem is in picker of combobox. Store filter is clearing properly, but picker doesn't refresh. I've made it work in this fiddle with listener, but it's not the best descision fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/j6s –  Nikolay Lopin 21 mins ago